# Separate conditioned rows into 2 columns in SQL Select

Tags: sql, database

The table is:

```
ID  Type
1   A
2   A
3   B
4   B
```

And the result after selecting should be:

```
ID1   ID2
1     3
2     4
```

What is the SQL query to get this result?

The number of items which has Type A and Type B is equal.

Comment: A little explanation would help. Also please tag the correct dbms.

Comment: What if the table has 5 rows? What if there is no ID=4, but an ID=10 instead?

Comment: Sorry, added: The number of items which has Type A and Type B is equal.

Comment: Looks like pivot  problem plus row_number partitioned by `Type`. Search pivot for your DBMS. In the worst case  when number of `Type` values is not fixed, it's dynamic Sql pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and use that in `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    ID1 = MIN(ID),
    ID2 = MAX(ID)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Id)
    FROM tbl
) t
GROUP BY rn
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/501597)</kbd>